# Excel VBA Run Time Error "1004" Method 'GetOpenFilename' of object_ Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro in Excel on one of my computers that runs perfectly fine with no errors. I emailed the spreadsheet with the macro to my other computer to use; however, when I run it, I get a Run Time Error "1004": Method `GetOpenFilename` of object_ Application' failed. I get this error on the `f1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*xl*;*xm*")` line of code.

I am super confused why I get an error on one computer and no error on another computer.

```
Sub Everything()

Dim f1 As String
Dim f2 As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook


f1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*xl*;*xm*")
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(f1)

f2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*xl*;*xm*")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(f2)

Call macro1

wb2.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:D25").Copy _
wb1.Worksheets("User Add-in Location").Range("E11:E32")

wb2.Close Savechanges:=False


End Sub
```

macro1 is just another macro being used that is in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Are these both PC's running Windows, or is one of these a MAC?  What versions are the operating systems? What versions are the Excels?

Comment: The computer I coded the macro on was on Windows. The computer I emailed the macro to is a MAC. Excel versions are the same: the newest one. Idk what versions the operating systems are: the MAC is new the windows pc is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

The file filters aren't correctly structured. Maybe the other computer is running a version of Excel that can't handle the incorrect structure.

Try this:

`f1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")`